# How to add Key/Value in return JSON object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am getting json object as a response. I want to add a new key/value pair in that object.
I tried object.assign but its overriding the value.
Is there any way to add the new key/value field in response object

```
{
"0": {
    "createdDate": "2021-11-08T19:51:02.000Z",
    "description": null,
    "id": "0TO7e000000RJMBGA4",
    "images": {
        "coverImageUrl": null,
        "featuredImageUrl": "/customercommunityv4/file-asset/structuresicongoldpng?v=1"
    },
    "isBeingDeleted": false,
    "name": "Structures",
    "nonLocalizedName": "Structures",
    "talkingAbout": 1,
    "url": "/services/data/v52.0/connect/communities/0DB7e000000GmlRGAS/topics/0TO7e000000RJMBGA4"
    
},
"1": {
    "createdDate": "2021-11-08T19:49:56.000Z",
    "description": null,
    "id": "0TO7e000000RJLrGAO",
    "images": {
        "coverImageUrl": null,
        "featuredImageUrl": "/customercommunityv4/file-asset/X3ddesigniconyellowpng?v=1"
    },
    "isBeingDeleted": false,
    "name": "Class3Error",
    "nonLocalizedName": "Class3Error",
    "talkingAbout": 1,
    "url": "/services/data/v52.0/connect/communities/0DB7e000000GmlRGAS/topics/0TO7e000000RJLrGAO"
},
"2": {
    "createdDate": "2021-11-08T19:50:12.000Z",
    "description": null,
    "id": "0TO7e000000RJLwGAO",
    "images": {
        "coverImageUrl": null,
        "featuredImageUrl": "/customercommunityv4/file-asset/X202101icondigitaltwingold120x120png?v=1"
    },
    "isBeingDeleted": false,
    "name": "Digital Twin",
    "nonLocalizedName": "Digital Twin",
    "talkingAbout": 1,
    "url": "/services/data/v52.0/connect/communities/0DB7e000000GmlRGAS/topics/0TO7e000000RJLwGAO"
},
```

}

I want to add 'newUrl' key and its corresponding value in this object after "url" field.
Like

```
"0": {
    "createdDate": "2021-11-08T19:51:02.000Z",
    "description": null,
    "id": "0TO7e000000RJMBGA4",
    "images": {
        "coverImageUrl": null,
        "featuredImageUrl": "/customercommunityv4/file-asset/structuresicongoldpng?v=1"
    },
    "isBeingDeleted": false,
    "name": "Structures",
    "nonLocalizedName": "Structures",
    "talkingAbout": 1,
    "url": "/services/data/v52.0/connect/communities/0DB7e000000GmlRGAS/topics/0TO7e000000RJMBGA4",
   "newUrl": "test/112/testname"    
},
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Regarding all the answers / solutions / approaches are there any questions left?

Comment: No questions left now. I found the solution. Thanks!

Comment: In case you found the solution yourself, you could share it so everybody does learn. In case you got inspired by other answers, it is considered at SO to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to provide some feedback and/or vote on answers and/or *accept the answer which was the most helpful* in solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to parse your `responseData` and then manipulate it.

```js
const newObj = JSON.parse(responseData);

Object.entries(newObj).forEach(([key, value]) => newObj[key] = { ...value, newUrl: '...' });
```

Or if you only want to add `newUrl` to a specific sub-object:

```js
const newObj = JSON.parse(obj);

newObj[key] = { ...newObj[key], newUrl: '...' };
```

Then you can `JSON.stringify(newObj)` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Following methods will be used ...

- [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
- [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (non mutating approach) [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) (mutating approach)
- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) (non mutating approach) [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (mutating approach)

Creating a new augmented object from the existing response data (non mutating approach) ...

```js
const responseData = {
  "0": {
    "createdDate": "2021-11-08T19:51:02.000Z",
    "description": null,
    "id": "0TO7e000000RJMBGA4",
    "images": {
      "coverImageUrl": null,
      "featuredImageUrl": "/customercommunityv4/file-asset/structuresicongoldpng?v=1"
    },
    "isBeingDeleted": false,
    "name": "Structures",
    "nonLocalizedName": "Structures",
    "talkingAbout": 1,
    "url": "/services/data/v52.0/connect/communities/0DB7e000000GmlRGAS/topics/0TO7e000000RJMBGA4"
  },
  "1": {
    "createdDate": "2021-11-08T19:49:56.000Z",
    "description": null,
    "id": "0TO7e000000RJLrGAO",
    "images": {
      "coverImageUrl": null,
      "featuredImageUrl": "/customercommunityv4/file-asset/X3ddesigniconyellowpng?v=1"
    },
    "isBeingDeleted": false,
    "name": "Class3Error",
    "nonLocalizedName": "Class3Error",
    "talkingAbout": 1,
    "url": "/services/data/v52.0/connect/communities/0DB7e000000GmlRGAS/topics/0TO7e000000RJLrGAO"
  },
  "2": {
    "createdDate": "2021-11-08T19:50:12.000Z",
    "description": null,
    "id": "0TO7e000000RJLwGAO",
    "images": {
      "coverImageUrl": null,
      "featuredImageUrl": "/customercommunityv4/file-asset/X202101icondigitaltwingold120x120png?v=1"
    },
    "isBeingDeleted": false,
    "name": "Digital Twin",
    "nonLocalizedName": "Digital Twin",
    "talkingAbout": 1,
    "url": "/services/data/v52.0/connect/communities/0DB7e000000GmlRGAS/topics/0TO7e000000RJLwGAO"
  }
};

const augmentedCopy = Object
  .entries(responseData)
  .reduce((result, [key, value]) =>
    Object.assign(result, {
      [key]: { ...value, newUrl: `test/${ key }/testname` }
    }), {}
  );

console.log({ augmentedCopy, responseData })
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Altering/mutating the existing response data (mutating approach) ...

```js
const responseData = {
  "0": {
    "createdDate": "2021-11-08T19:51:02.000Z",
    "description": null,
    "id": "0TO7e000000RJMBGA4",
    "images": {
      "coverImageUrl": null,
      "featuredImageUrl": "/customercommunityv4/file-asset/structuresicongoldpng?v=1"
    },
    "isBeingDeleted": false,
    "name": "Structures",
    "nonLocalizedName": "Structures",
    "talkingAbout": 1,
    "url": "/services/data/v52.0/connect/communities/0DB7e000000GmlRGAS/topics/0TO7e000000RJMBGA4"
  },
  "1": {
    "createdDate": "2021-11-08T19:49:56.000Z",
    "description": null,
    "id": "0TO7e000000RJLrGAO",
    "images": {
      "coverImageUrl": null,
      "featuredImageUrl": "/customercommunityv4/file-asset/X3ddesigniconyellowpng?v=1"
    },
    "isBeingDeleted": false,
    "name": "Class3Error",
    "nonLocalizedName": "Class3Error",
    "talkingAbout": 1,
    "url": "/services/data/v52.0/connect/communities/0DB7e000000GmlRGAS/topics/0TO7e000000RJLrGAO"
  },
  "2": {
    "createdDate": "2021-11-08T19:50:12.000Z",
    "description": null,
    "id": "0TO7e000000RJLwGAO",
    "images": {
      "coverImageUrl": null,
      "featuredImageUrl": "/customercommunityv4/file-asset/X202101icondigitaltwingold120x120png?v=1"
    },
    "isBeingDeleted": false,
    "name": "Digital Twin",
    "nonLocalizedName": "Digital Twin",
    "talkingAbout": 1,
    "url": "/services/data/v52.0/connect/communities/0DB7e000000GmlRGAS/topics/0TO7e000000RJLwGAO"
  }
};

Object
  .values(responseData)
  .forEach((value, idx) =>
    value.newUrl = `test/${ idx }/testname`
    // ... OR ...
    // // Object.assign(value, {newUrl: `test/${ idx }/testname` })
  );

console.log({ responseData })
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```